# UITextView not shifting up with the keyboard

Tags: swift3, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've spent most of the day on SO trying to figure this out, here's my problem:

I have a `UIScrollView` with a vertical stack view inside of it, and inside of the stack view I have several `UIView`s that contain different stuff. In the bottom view, I have a `UITextView` that I'd ideally like to move up whenever I start typing in it so I can actually see what I'm typing.

Implementing the solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100545/swift-scroll-the-view-up-when-keyboard-shows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252589/move-view-when-keyboard-appears-and-present-it-in-a-scrollview-swift-3),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070242/move-view-with-keyboard-using-swift),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693130/move-textfield-when-keyboard-appears-swift), and all the other similar prior questions on this topic works if I have a `UITextField` in the last view instead of a `UITextView`, but I really would like to have return key / multi-line functionality which seems to necessitate a `UITextView`.

Here's what I have in terms of code (per the several above links):

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    guard let info = notification.userInfo, let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

I've called `registerForKeyboardNotifications()` in `viewDidLoad()`, and this is working *perfectly* when I use a `UITextField`, but for whatever reason the functionality doesn't work with a `UITextView`. The closest SO question I could find to my issue is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957579/textview-in-tableview-cell-not-moving-up-when-keyboard-hide-it-in-swift), but the question was never answered with a workable solution involving `UITextView`. I've seen several posts mention [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager), but I'd ideally like to fix this natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that combines `contentInset` and `setContentOffset`, but I'm sure it's not the most elegant one out there. However, if anyone else is having trouble getting a `textView` to move up with `keyBoardWasShown`, you can do the following:

Set up your `viewController` to notice when the keyboard shows up;

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    guard let info = notification.userInfo, let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

Make sure to call `registerForKeyboardNotifications()` in `viewDidLoad`.

This is where it will vary depending on your particular setup. Since I had a `view` covering most of the screen real estate, I really only wanted my `scrollView` (which I made into an `IBOutlet`) to jump up enough to show part of my `textView` so that the user would know it was there and editable. This resulted in the following changes to the above portions of code dealing with the keyboard shown/hidden state;

```
func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    guard let info = notification.userInfo, let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height - 50.0, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    let bottom = keyboardSize.height - 60.0
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated: true)

}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: NSNotification) {

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

}
```

The key item being the `scrollView.setContentOffset` part.